# The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, slf4j

I got this error in my maven project, which I'm not able to solve.
How can I solve it?

I tried all possible things with **right click on project**.
Update project, Download Source, ... ).

And I got **slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar** in Maven depencies.
Why does it fail on load ?

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building guacamole-tutorial 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.0 is missing, no dependency information available
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.427s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 25 10:51:17 EET 2015
    [INFO] Final Memory: 4M/76M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.0: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:3.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is simply that no version 3.0 of the maven-war-plugin exists.

The most recent version of [maven-war-plugin is 2.6](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Overview for all plugins can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks , I was writing compliler version.